# How to retrieve data after the 1st occurence of a number/digit in a string in php

Tags: php, mysql

We have a query(mysql) which returns data in the following format of  alphabets followed by digits followed by alphabets like --
text1 12.12 mg text2

Now the issue is , i need to write a script in php which gives all the data starting from the 1st digit.so the result should be something like

12.12 mg text2

I am not sure how to accomplish this in php and the functions which might be of use for this purpose.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_match('#\\d+(.*)$#', $message, $match);
$text = $match[1];
```

the `\\d+` means one or more consecutive digits.  `(.*)` means match any character except a new line.  `$` tells it to go to the end of the string...

Comment: thank you very much.also does this accept special characters like %

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `\d+`? I mean only one `\\` ?

Comment: @swathi yes, the `.` matches any character except `\n`...  @Felix Kling yes and no, the double ` \\ ` just forces a literal ` \ ` inside of the string.  With a single quote it's redundant, but I'm just in the habit of always doing it.  @OMG Ponies: Right on.  It has good REGEXP support for where clauses, but very little for fields...

Comment: @ircmaxell,
when i am trying to use this code it gives me all the characters after the first few digits,for ex:it gives me - mg text2 instead of 12.12 mg text2.any suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure there's a space after the digit?  If it's only ever a single digit, you could change the regexp to `'#^\\D*\\d(.*)$#'`, which says any number of non-digit characters from the start of the string (`^\\D`), then a single digit character (`\\d`) then anything following up to the end...